# Are there efficiency differences in extend vs. adding vs. appending in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I refer to list operations:

```
L = myList + otherList
L = myList.append([5])
L = myList.extend(otherList)
```

I am curious if there are efficiency differences among these operations.

Comment: Append only adds one element to the list. You should append each element in a loop for a fair comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example here is sort of misleading in the case of `append`.

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l1.append([5])
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3, 4, [5]]
```

Append takes a single item and appends it to the end of the existing list. By passing in an iterable to append, you're adding another list (in this case) within a list.

`extend` takes an iterable and essentially calls `append` for each item in the iterable`, adding the items onto the end of the existing list.

The `mylist + otherlist` is the only interesting case here, as the result of using the `+` operator creates a new list, using more memory.

Comment: Sorry I meant, say, L.extend(otherList) versus L+=otherList

Comment: I addressed that at the end of my answer. `extend` operates on the existing list in-place, + creates a new list with the items from both.

Comment: So if I have L += otherList it creates a completely new list, putting a copy of L and otherList inside it, and then assigns that to L?

Answer (score 5):

These are totally different operations.

They have different purposes, so efficiency wouldn't matter. `append` is used to append a single value to a list, `extend` is used for multiple values, and the addition is for when you don't want to modify the original list, but to have another list with the extra values added on.

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> lst2 = [5, 6]
>>> lst.append(4)  # appending
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> lst.extend(lst2)  # extending
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> lst + lst2  # addition
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6]
```

Also note that `list.append` and `list.extend` operate *in-place*, so assigning the result to a variable will make that variable hold the value `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Timing them answers your question about efficiency in regards of speed:

```
import timeit

def first():
    mylist + otherlist

def second():
    mylist.append(otherlist)

def third():
    mylist.extend(otherlist)

for test in (first, second, third):
    mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    otherlist = [5]

    print "%s: %f" % (test, timeit.timeit(test, number=1000000))
```

On my machine the result was:

```
<function first at 0x10ff3ba28>: 0.320835
<function second at 0x10ff3baa0>: 0.275077
<function third at 0x10ff3bb18>: 0.284508
```

Showing that the first example was clearly slowest.